# How can i get from a string not only match cases?

Tags: c#

This is my code:

```
public static void ColorListBox(List<string> data, DrawItemEventArgs e, string word)
        {
            int keywords = 0;
            string keyword = null;
            string url = data[e.Index].Substring(0, 5);
            if (data[e.Index].Contains(word))//"Local KeyWord:"))
            {
                keywords = data[e.Index].IndexOf(word);//"Local KeyWord:");
                keyword = data[e.Index].Substring(keywords, word.Length);
            }
            else
            {
                keywords = data[e.Index].IndexOf(word);//"Localy KeyWord:");
                keyword = data[e.Index].Substring(keywords, 15);
            }
```

The problem in in Form1 when im calling this function:

```
ColorText.ColorListBox(data, e);
```

How do I know wich text to add ? `ColorText.ColorListBox(data, e, "Local KeyWord");` or `ColorText.ColorListBox(data, e, "Localy KeyWord");` Since when im running my program it's Localy KeyWord but when im adding a new url it's "Local KeyWord"

I need in Form1 when calling the function to cover all the options.
Before I added the variable word I used manual strings "Local KeyWord" and "Localy Keyword" but now I want to do something that each word or words I will enter as word will be used in the function.

The problem is when im running my program the strings in the variable data are "Localy KeyWord:"
And when I add a new url while the program is working then in data the strings are "Local KeyWord:"

Comment: compare loware case version of your reference string to lowere'd data http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.tolower.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is not just a case comparison, but actually different words, I would get rid of these differences as soon as possible:

```
private const string LocalKeyword = "Local Keyword";
private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> keywords = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
{
    { "Localy KeyWord:", LocalKeyword },
    { "Localy Keyword", LocalKeyword },
    { "Local Keyword:", LocalKeyword },
    { ... }
}

if (!keywords.TryGetValue(rawKeyword, out realKeyword))
{
    throw new ApplicationException("Unknown keyword or keyword alias!");
}
ColorText.ColorListBox(realKeyword, e)
```